# Regex to remove text between / /

Tags: java, regex

line: bp(k)      "by products"    / text... /

I have this line and I need a regex to remove everything between // (not //). Any ideas?

I have tried:

`line = line.replaceAll("/.*?/", "/"+"/")` but it wont work

**Edit:** (sometimes I forget people cant read my mind :P)

I need everything to be removed between / and /. Init there can be letters,',' or '_'.
With the replacement I tried, it will leave the text as it is, no errors though

Comment: What is your input? What output does this produce? What is the expected output?

Comment: What if the input line is `blah/ blah / blah / more blah`... or has 4 or 5 slashes?  You need to think about all the cases that _might_ occur in the input and decide how you want to handle them.  Until you do that the problem is under-specified.

Comment: That's a string, not a regex.

Comment: if you have line smth like this `/some words/` then it will be suitable `^/(.*)/$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.*` is greedy - It's matching the closing '/' and anything else until the last '/' found in the line. Read up on [regex usage](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html), and try `line = line.replaceAll("/[^/]+/", "//");`

Answer (score 1):

Globally find `/[^/]+(?=/)` replace `/`

Turns  `/ this / that /`  into `///`